# Intrusion Detection System hardware requirement for a home user

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm new to network security

I have an old computer I'd like turn into an IDS (Linux using Snort IDS) to monitor my home wireless network. Problem is, what hardware do I need to be able to sniff all network traffic going to and from my router and how would I setup so that the computer is able to sniff all network traffic going through the network

thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Two NICs on an old machine running pfsense will do the trick.

> Hardware considerations
>
> When selecting hardware for a new build, carefully consider current
>   and future hardware requirements. These include:
>
> ```
> 64-bit Intel or AMD CPU (x86-64, amd64) on pfSense 2.4 and later (Q2 2017)
> CPUs must have AES-NI support on pfSense 2.5 and later (TBD, 2018+)
> Must be able to boot from USB or optical drive and run the installer on pfSense 2.4 and later
> ```

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Installing_pfSense

---

Really two NICs would be fine. Or you would need a network tap or a switch that is capable of port mirroring.

Comment: Considered that, but I'd like to run Snort independently on a Linux distribution to sniff all network traffic on a network, not turn my old computer into a router

Comment: Makes sense.  Really two NICs would be fine.  


Or you would need a network tap or a switch that is capable of port mirroring.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how would i setup the 2 NICs ?
Do i just Plug them both into the LAN ports of my router then my IDS computer ?

Comment: Setting Up A Snort IDS on Debian Linux - http://www.aboutdebian.com/snort.htm

Comment: I've Done that it seems to be only capturing traffic going from and to that computer and not seeing my other laptop pinging my router. Also my router has integrated modem so

Comment: Ah, now this is where it gets complicated.  Ideally the device (in this situation, your computer) is inline, between a router and a switch, or between a modem and a SOHO router.  If you don't want to put your machine inline you'll need to use a network tap, which can be expensive. 

Another thing that you may be able to do would be to drop a hub inline, a real hub that mirrors all packets out of all ports, and connect it to NIC1 in promiscuous mode, then connect NIC2 to your switch/router.

Comment: Comments should not be used for extended discussions.

Comment: Will this method allow sniffing of internal network traffic so like traffic going from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.3